# Insert content of a post into another

Tags: plugins, wp-query, loop, shortcode

I am writing a little plugin that creates a **custom post** type.

I created a filter that **copies the content** of such a post into another one.

Thereby I loop through all the custom posts. For each one I get a `target_type` field value of it.

This value is compared to the actual `post_type` of the viewed post. If it is the same the content will be appended.

**My problem is** that shortcodes that are used in the custom post content shall be rendered in the context of the target post.

For Example: I have a shortcode used in the custom post, that just returns `get_the_title();` In the target post this shows the title of the custom post.

In fact I want the custom post just to be a container for later rendered content.

Wow this was actually hard to explain for me.

I hope someone understands my issue and can help me out.

Thank you in advance!

Here is the filter code:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'copy_content');
function copy_content( $content )
{

    $post_type = get_post_type();

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'custom',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    $post_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if($post_query->have_posts() ) {
      while($post_query->have_posts() ) {
        $post_query->the_post();
        $target_type = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "target_type")[0];
        if($target_type == $post_type){
            return $content . get_the_content();
        }
      }
    }

  wp_reset_postdata();

  return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use return in your function, the rest of the function will not run. It work somehow like `exit();` or `die();`, but it won't terminate the entire script, only ends that particular piece of code in your function, and return a value if necessary.

You should save your content into a string, and then return it all after you are finished.

So, that's how your code should look like:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'copy_content');
function copy_content( $content )
{

    $post_type = get_post_type();

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'custom',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    $post_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if($post_query->have_posts() ) {
      // Create an empty string
      $data = '';
      while($post_query->have_posts() ) {
        $post_query->the_post();
        $target_type = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "target_type")[0];
        if($target_type == $post_type){
            // Append each post's content to it
            $data .= get_the_content();
        }
      }
    }

  wp_reset_postdata();
  // Return both content and our custom data altogether
  return $content . $data;
}
```